# Python multipy file content

Tags: python, file, operating-system, numbers

I'm working on file contains a few lines of numerical sequences. I want to multiply some part of this string. How am I supposed to do it? When I just do 'num[10:](which is for ex 2)*4' (like below) it prints me '2' four times, I want to print 8.

```
import os
from datetime import date

with open('C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\python\\Y\\Z.txt') as file:
    numbers = file.readlines()


def last_number():
    for num in numbers:
        last = num[10:]
        x = last*4
        print(x)
last_number()
```

Comment: `last = int(num[10:])` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading a file you read it in string format.
In order to do math operations with the content you must convert it to an `int` or a `float`.

Specifically if you know the exact location of the numbers in your code you should try this, notice i also sent `numbers` as a parameter for the function:

```
import os
from datetime import date

with open('C:\\Users\\X\\Desktop\\python\\Y\\Z.txt') as file:
    numbers = file.readlines()


def last_number(numbers):
    # numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]
    # prev line will create a list of numbers in integer form for you
    for num in numbers:
        last = int(num[10:])
        x = last*4
        print(x)
last_number()
```